# Re-map the <esc> key for switching to normal mode

Tags: vimrc

I'd like to re-map the `<esc>` key for switching to normal mode from edit mode. It just feels to far out of the way for me. I heard some have mapped this to the `<caps lock>` key instead. Can anyone show how to do this and what other key they might have used?

Comment: This is done at the OS level; my caps lock is configured to send control, but I think esc is an option. Anyway, dont remap esc itself to anything (breaks a lot of stuff). I found the jk tip below to get in my way after a few years of use, but ymmv

Comment: As mentioned by [DBK](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/re-map-the-esc-key-for-switching-to-normal-mode#comment44020_25144) I, too, think mapping `caps lock` to `ctrl` is the way to go. `ctrl` is mandatory in vim, and having it on the home row of the keyboard makes life easier. If you do this, `esc` is then available quite easily with `ctrl-[`.

Comment: Thanks! I think that mapping at the OS level should be a full answer as well. The comment by @filbranden directly lead me to the answer since I am on macOS. I like mapping `<caps lock>` to `<ctrl>` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really remap the CapsLock key in Vim, since the CapsLock key is typically undetectable from applications.

If you're on Mac OS and you have a fairly recent version of Mac OS X, then you can remap Caps Lock to Esc on the OS Preferences, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40254864/9447571).

If you're on a different OS and would like to remap CapsLock to Esc (or to Control), there should be ways to do that, either search for it online or ask a question about it on a more appropriate Stack Exchange site where OS keyboard mappings will be on topic. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I like using j and then k entered quickly. To map I have this in my .vimrc file.

```
inoremap jk <esc>
```

It's really easy to learn to use those together.